# Kotlin - Get a List of classes implementing generic interface preserving type visibility

Tags: kotlin, generics, reflection, polymorphism

Given this generic interface:

```
interface Trick<I, T> {
   fun perform(input: I): T
}
```

I want to get a List of all classes implementing this interface, like this:

`fun <I,T>loadTricks(): List<Trick<I, T>>`

I already tried to use [Google's Auto-Service library](https://github.com/google/auto/tree/main/service) but all I was able to get was a list of type `List<Trick<*, *>!>`, which I think will be a problem as I desired to preserve the visibility on the actual type each implementation uses.

I've also came across the [Reflections library](https://github.com/ronmamo/reflections), but that one is no longer being actively supported and, as such, I'd like to avoid it.

Maybe I am even going the wrong way about all this, so I'll just explain what I am aiming to achieve:

- I want a list of all Tricks preserving the information of what Trick each of them is, the input I need to pass to "perform" and what output to expect from it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you already mentioned Auto-Service and Reflections, I assume you know how to find the `Class` or `KClass` itself. I'll skip that part. Then the only remaining part is how to use Kotlin reflection to get `I` and `T`. This is more advanced usage, but it is not that hard neither:

```kotlin
fun main() {
    val clazz = IntToStringTrick::class
    val baseType = clazz.supertypes.single { it.classifier == Trick::class }
    println("I: ${baseType.arguments[0]}") // Int
    println("T: ${baseType.arguments[1]}") // String
}

class IntToStringTrick : Trick<Int, String> {
    override fun perform(input: Int) = input.toString()
}
```

`baseType.arguments[0]` returns a `KTypeProjection`. Depending on your needs, you can acquire the variance from it. The type of `I` as `KClass` can be acquired with:

```kotlin
baseType.arguments[0].type?.classifier as? KClass<*>
```

You need to be careful though. If the implementation of `Trick` is itself generic, then the `classifier` is not a `KClass`, so the above returns null. There may be other tricky cases, for example documentation mentions star projections and intersection types, but I think both of them are not possible in your case. Anyway, the above code should safely return either `KClass` or `null` for any such tricky cases. You could provide additional handling for these cases.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, it would work but the code is getting busier by the second so I'll just take a step back and see if this is really the best path.

I will accept you answer anyway, many thanks.